# How can I put dot thousand in yaxis using plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I have this code

```
 output$result<-renderPlotly({
   dades_graf <- dades[which(dades$Plataforma==input$Plataforma & dades$Jugador==input$Jugador),]
   p <-plot_ly(data=dades_graf, x= dades_graf$Fecha, y= dades_graf$Valor, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 

     layout(separators= ".",
         autosize = TRUE,
         title="Valor Jugadores", 
         xaxis=list(title="Fecha"),
         yaxis=list(title="Valor", tickformat= "d"))
          })
```

and the result is this

[image]

How can do I to put '.' on thousands values in 'y'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `layout.yaxis.tickformat=",d"` and `layout.separators=",."`.